# Can I rename my craft/ folder?

Tags: admin, install

I have one site on my server that's currently using Craft, and I'd like to setup a second one to use Craft as well. Can I rename the craft folder, and then set the $craftPath variable to point to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely! In fact, you've outlined the steps needed to do so...

1. Rename `craft` folder
2. Change `$craftPath` value in `index.php`

That's it!

Comment: Thanks Lindsey - I thought I could, but it telling me it couldn't connect. I didn't read the error message all the way through (one of my big faults, I just automatically assume...), and it was having a problem connecting to the database. Typed in my user name wrong.  Whoops.